# unknown reason for broken javascript button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, prettyphoto

I have been slowly building a portfolio site for quite a while now, and I have made use of a few simple scripts. recently, some of these scripts have stopped working.

For reference, here is my site: http://www.jcstudios.org

The meta link on the bottom left hand side of the page is supposed to bring up a login form in place of the navigation menu and would then toggle back and forth as clicked. However, recently this javascript button has broken. I noticed it happened not long after installing the prettyphoto plugin to my site. If it is the case that this is messing up my scripts, I would like to find a fix as this plugin is one of the only plugins able to achieve what I am looking for. Any ideas why this script stopped working?

Here is the script, but I assure you that it worked fine for a while before spontaneously breaking.

```
$('.togglemeta').toggle(function(){
    $('.togglemeta').text('Site Nav')
    $('#meta').css('display', 'block');
    $('#sitenav').css('display', 'none');
},function(){
    $('.togglemeta').text('Meta')
    $('#meta').css('display', 'none');
    $('#sitenav').css('display', 'block');
})
```

Currently, this button is broken and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably upgraded jQuery, and in version 1.9.1, which is what you are using now, the `toggle()` function used that way is deprecated and removed, and now it only hides and shows elements.

You'll have to create your own toggle functionality instead :

```
$('.togglemeta').on('click', function(){
    var state = $(this).data('state');

    if (state) {
        $('.togglemeta').text('Meta')
        $('#meta').css('display', 'none');
        $('#sitenav').css('display', 'block');
    }else{
        $('.togglemeta').text('Site Nav')
        $('#meta').css('display', 'block');
        $('#sitenav').css('display', 'none');
    }

    $(this).data('state', !state);
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, @adeneo. That worked. I was unaware of the depreciation of the toggle function during jquery 1.9.1